# NET Core MongoDb Update/Replace exclude fields

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, repository, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to complete a general repository for all of the entities in my application. I Have a `BaseEntity` with property `Id`, `CreatorId` and `LastModifiedUserId`. Now I'd like to Update a record in a collection, without having to modify the field `CreatorId`, so I have (from the client) an Entity valorized with some fields updated that I want to update. 
Hi have 2 ways:

1. UpdateOneAsync
2. ReplaceOneAsync

The repo is created like this:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity 
{
   public async Task<T> Replace/Update(T entity){...}
}
```

So it's very hard to use Update(1), since I should retrieve with reflection all the fields of T and exclude the ones that I don't want to update.
With Replace(2) I cannot find a way to specify which fields i should exclude when replacing an object with another. `Projection`property in `FindOneAndReplaceOptions<T>()` just excludes the fields on the document that is returned after the update.

Am I missing a way in the `replace` method to exclude the fields or should I try to retrieve the fields with reflection and use a `Update`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution is ok for you .. what i do is :

Declare in Base Repo a method like

```
 public virtual bool Update(TEntity entity, string key)
        {
            var result = _collection.ReplaceOne(x => x.Id.Equals(key), entity, new UpdateOptions
            {

                IsUpsert = false
            });

            return result.IsAcknowledged;
        }
```

then in your controller when you want to update your entities is there where you set the prop you want to change .. like:

```
  [HttpPut]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(OrderDTO), 200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Put([FromBody] OrderDTO value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var orderOnDb = await _orderService.FindAsync(xx => xx.Id == value.Id);
            if (orderOnDb == null) return BadRequest(Constants.Error.NOT_FOUND_ON_MONGO);


            // SET PROPERTY TO UPDATE (MANUALLY)
            orderOnDb.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            orderOnDb.PaymentMethod = value.PaymentMethod;
            orderOnDb.StateHistory = value.StateHistory;

            //Save on db
            var res = await _orderRepo.UpdateAsync(orderOnDb, orderOnDb.Id);

            return res;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical(ex, ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you!!!

Comment: This is how I'm doing it right now... But I hate to execute a query to read the actual parameters and then another to update it. Since the object that I receive from the client has nearly everything.

Comment: yes .. but personally ... i never would accept a entoity from client and update the one on DB without have a check and set manually the fields .. cause if someone do a put from his postman (or other tools) and send to you also other fields (maybe price of a order ??? ) .. you can't check it

Comment: but maybe is not your case ... a query in mongodb .. by Id if is possibile .. is not so expensive ...

Comment: In that case I would do a check, as I'm now, but for a lot of entities I don't need any check, for example a change in a User or stuff like that I only want to keep the creatorId

Comment: Yeah it's not expensive, but if there is a better way to handle this problem would be better. I find pretty strange that you cannot choose which fields to exclude

Comment: in Mongodb you can use some decoration to do so (like    [BsonIgnore]  ) .. but it will ignore it every time!!

Comment: Yeah, I know :/ The problem would not exists if the repo was single for each entity ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188143/discussion-between-federico-scamuzzi-and-davide-quaglio).